# Desktop icons specific to a certain workspace?

Tags: icons

I want certain to appear on certain workplace, for example:

I want the document.pdf to be on workspace 1 but not on the other workspaces(2,3,4,...) or on workspace 2 and not on the other workspaces(1,3,4,...).

using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I think one program opened in one work space won,t appear in another.Please explain if you experience the problem